# How to backup C:\ with a hidden drive as dell/hp does

Tags: backup

I want to know whether there is a software that I can use to create a hidden drive that contains the backup of the whole c:. The hidden drive can be used to recover the C: later.

I knew most of the laptop now uses this way to recover the machine to factory status.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a roll your own solution or a package?

[Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/) software appears to do what you want.

You could also install a boot manager like [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) and roll your own backup/recovery using a minimal Linux install and dd.